# Docker-machine create with generic driver, Certificates not working but SSH does

Tags: docker, certificate, docker-machine

Im trying to get a docker-machine up and running on a Ubuntu 14.04TSL server in our network. I have installed docker+docker-machine on the server and im able to create the docker-machine on the server with this command from my computer:

```
docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address 10.10.3.76 --generic-ssh-key "/Users/username/Documents/keys/mysshkey.pem" --generic-ssh-user ubuntuuser dockermachinename
```

The command above creates the docker-machine and im able to list it with

```
docker-machine ls
```

Im able to SSH to it by running

```
docker-machine ssh dockermachinename
```

but when i try to connect the server with (-D for debug information)

```
docker-machine -D env dockermachinename
```

I get the following message

```
Docker Machine Version: 0.5.2 ( 0456b9f )
Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-generic
Launching plugin server for driver generic
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:54213
() Calling .GetVersion
Using API Version 1
() Calling .SetConfigRaw
() Calling .GetMachineName
(dockermachinename) Calling .GetState
(dockermachinename) Calling .GetURL
Reading CA certificate from /Users/username/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem
Reading server certificate from /Users/username/.docker/machine/machines/dockermachinename/server.pem
Reading server key from /Users/username/.docker/machine/machines/dockermachinename/server-key.pem
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "10.10.3.76:2376": dial tcp 10.10.3.76:2376: i/o timeout
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which will stop running containers.
```

I really need to solve this so all help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `docker-machine regenerate-certs`?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu you will need to do following steps:

**1. Create user which don't require password**

```
sudo visudo
```

at the end of file add following line (make sure to specify your username):

```
username    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and then save and exit. And after that add your username to docker group like this (change **username** with your actual username):

```
usermod -aG docker username
```

**2. Edit docker config to open 2375 and 2376 ports**

```
sudo systemctl edit docker.service
```

add following snippet to that file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

then save and exit. After that reload config and restart docker deamon with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

**3. Create docker-machine**

Remove existing machine which is failing with:

```
docker-machine rm machine1
```

and try to create it one more time like this:

```
docker-machine create -d generic --generic-ip-address ip --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/key --generic-ssh-user username --generic-ssh-port 22 machine1
```

please change ip, key, username and machine1 with you actual values.

If this produce error like this:

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.0.26:2376": tls: oversized record received with length 20527
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.
```

then SSH to your machine and cd into following directory:

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
```

list all files in it with:

```
ls -l
```

you will probably have something like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  274 Jul  2 17:47 10-machine.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  101 Jul  2 17:46 override.conf
```

you will need to delete all files except 10-machine.conf with **sudo rm**.

After that remove machine you created and create it again. It should now work. I hope this helps. Maybe you already steps 1 and 2 if so then skip them and just try to remove override.conf file or any file in that dir which is not 10-machine.conf.